# HttpClient in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, import, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

How can I use [`HttpComponents`](http://hc.apache.org/index.html) [(Download)](http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.2.5-bin.zip) 4.2.5 to in order to make the [`QuickStart`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/QuickStart.java) example compatible in Netbeans 7.3?

In Eclipse everything works fine, creating a custom library with the path to the lib/ was enough.

Comment: Simplified significantly, please do not link files without explaining what they are in case they are removed at some point.

Comment: There is a name of the file in each of the URLs, so your edition improved absolutely NOTHING!

Comment: Actually it improved your English, your link style, and readability. Rest assured I received no rep from the editor, it's purely charity

Comment: Maybe you could help me with my issue, rather than my style?

Comment: As someone with higher rep, one of my volunteer responsibilities on this site is to help newer users and clarify questions. Simply linking two files and asking how to make one equal the other is not usually acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

1. Choose File, Project Properties. The Project Properties dialog opens.
2. Click Libraries in the Categories pane, and then click the Add Library button. The Add Library dialog opens.
3. Click the Create button. The Create New Library dialog opens.
4. Enter e.g. HTTPClient in the Library Name field and click OK. The Customize Library dialog opens.
5. Click Add JAR/Folder. The Browser JAR/Folder dialog opens.
6. Find the folder where you saved unpacked HTTPClient and choose ALL the JAR files in the lib folder. Click Add JAR/Folder.
7. In the Customize Library dialog, click OK.
8. In the Add Library dialog, choose HTTPClient and click Add Library.
9. In the Project Properties dialog, click OK.

Based on R. Cadenhead "Sams Teach Yourself Java in 24 Hours" [p. 303].